# Return an argument's name instead of its value - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to print the result of a .max function, but displaying the name of its argument, not its target value (a number) used by the `.max` method.

```
def who_is_bigger(a,b,c)
  "#{[a,b,c].max} is bigger"
end
```

Expected result :

```
expect(who_is_bigger(84, 42, 21)).to eq("a is bigger")
expect(who_is_bigger(42, 84, 21)).to eq("b is bigger")
expect(who_is_bigger(42, 21, 84)).to eq("c is bigger")
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, there's not an effortless or easy-to-understand way to get the name of an argument from its value. (See the bottom of the answer for one way of doing it like this.)

Instead, here's the way I'd do it, which I think is nice and readable:

```
def who_is_bigger(a,b,c)
  values = {a: a, b: b, c: c}
  largest_key, _ = values.max_by { |key, value| value }
  "#{largest_key} is bigger"
end
```

This works as follows:

1. Build a hash out of the arguments, and store it in `values`. For example, this hash could be `{ a: 84, b: 42, c: 21 }`.
2. Find the largest value in that hash using the [`Enumerable#max_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max_by) method. This will store an array of 2 items in `largest_pair`, such as `[:a, 84]`. Notice how the key we want is the first item, so we use destructuring to extract the first item of that pair and store it in `largest_key`.
3. Construct the string and return it from the method.

---

If you'd like to do this in such a way where you are accessing and iterating the names and values of the parameters dynamically, you could use this:

```
def who_is_bigger(a,b,c)
  params = method(__method__).parameters
  values = params.map { |_, name| [name, binding.local_variable_get(name)] }.to_h
  largest_key, _ = values.max_by { |key, value| value }
  "#{largest_key} is bigger"
end
```

In my opinion though, this feels a bit hacky and harder-to-read than the other solution.

Comment: You could use `largest_key, largest_value = values.max_by { ... }` to assign key and value to separate variables.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that'd look much cleaner!

Comment: Your first sentence suggests that there is a way to get the name from the value, though it is hard to understand or requires effort. If you know that to be true you should at least outline the procedure; if you do not know that to be true you should not suggest it. Also, what does "really" mean in "there's not really..."? Be precise!

Comment: @CarySwoveland fair enough - added to the bottom of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do this using [`Binding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Binding.html) and [`max_by`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/max_by) from Ruby:

```
def who_is_bigger(a, b, c)
  biggest = binding.local_variables.max_by do |v|
              binding.local_variable_get(v) || -Float::INFINITY
            end
  "#{biggest} is biggest"
end

who_is_bigger(10, 21, 30)
=> "c is biggest"

who_is_bigger(40, 31, 30)
=> "a is biggest"
```